# Vim: Use file name in mapping without extension

Tags: vim

I have a command that let me jump to a specific nested yaml key called `:YamlGoToKey`, and I've mapped it to a shortcut.

```
nmap <leader>yx :YamlGoToKey<space>
```

Now I want to prepend the language of the file to the command, to save me some time when typing (and I can copy paste keys without the leading locale), e.g. it should look like this after the shortcut

```
:YamlGoToKey en.
```

I tried it with this mapping

```
nmap <leader>yx :YamlGoToKey<space>!shellescape(expand('%:t:r')).
```

but the result is

```
:YamlGoToKey<space>!shellescape(expand('%:t:r')).
```

So, how can I get the name of the current file, without the extension, to show up in my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (`:help c_CTRL-R_=`):

```
:nmap <leader>yx :YamlGoToKey <c-r>=expand('%:t:r')<cr>.
```

Comment: It is a general rule of thumb to use `*noremap` mappings to avoid recursive mappings. e.g. `nnoremap <leader>yx :YamlGoToKey <c-r>=expand('%:t:r')<cr>.` As this is a YAML specific mapping maybe think about making it a buffer-local mapping by putting the mapping inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim` and using `<buffer>`. e.g. `nnoremap <buffer> <leader>yx :YamlGoToKey <c-r>=expand('%:t:r')<cr>.`. See `:h :map-local`

Comment: @PeterRincker: All good suggestions. I hope OP is still around to note them.